# How to wrap a View output with a link?

Tags: views, javascript

I have a view with no fields but a special format (An openlayer map). I would like to wrap the whole output (a map) with a static link. Typically I would like something like:

```
<div class="view-content">
    <a href="some static url">
        /*the map*/
    </a>
</div>
```

Is this achievable?

**EDIT**
My view doesn't use fields, so I can't use custom texts fields.
[image: format]

Answer (score 1):

There might be a couple of method to do this.

**Using Views:** you can add a "Custom Text" global field and add view content to it and wrap it on the link or you can "Rewrite results" on the same file and output the field as a link.

**Using a template file:** view let you have a custom template file for your view, so you can use it to wrap your view content with the link.

**Using jQuery:** you can do something like this:

```
$('div.VIEW-CLASS').click(function(){document.location.href='URL.COM';});
```

And that will wrap the view on a link.

See the images below to see how to add a "Custom text" field and how to make it a link:

**Select custom text field**

[image: Select custom text]

**Add views fields into the custom text field and make it all a link**

[image: Add views fields into the custom text field]

Comment: I cannot add a view to a custom text. I could add a view area to the header/footer, but not rewrite results. I also have tried to add the following snippet in the header/footer but it didn't work: <script language='Javascript'>$('div.openlayers-views-map').click(function(){document.location.href='/somedir';});</script> . Is that the correct way to insert it? Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer with images. Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you Redhatlab,  my view doesn't use fields and I cannot transform it in fields as it's a map...

Comment: This is an interesting solution... Are changes in the hidden fields (like trimming) still applied?